# Laravel 5.5 not found error while URL project/public/login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I created Laravel 5.5 project in lamp system, included authentication by running make:auth in terminal, on loading localhost/project/public URL, this shows the welcome blade ,but when I click login or register links shows an error 'project/public not found'. If by running artisan serve in terminal it's working as it should be. Can anyone tell why this happens? How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run php artisan serve as then and then only server renders the files and gives you the output.
Without running the server you cannot get the output.
When you run php artisan serve it converts your blade files in php files and that is how you get the results.
**And its not an error**
This is how you access the project root in browser.

Comment: in live server i can't use those php artisan serve command right? then how can i run it? from searching i found by making domain root to project/public can make my system running. is there any other way to run my project? sorry for my bad english.

Comment: actually you don't need to use php artisan serve on your live server but if in any scenario u need it then you can connect to your server from terminal by using "ssh username@server_address"  command and then u will get access to files of your server. There you can run artisan commands inside the laravel project folder. If you are satisfied with the answer then please upvote the answer.

Comment: Actually i want to load the site without using artisan serv command, I put my laraval Project folder contents in host. But i can't run it by site-name/public/login as url. Can help me make it working

Comment: it looks like u do not know how to deploy the site on the hosting server.

Comment: Please search about deploying your website on shared hosing and you will find the process to follow. I would suggest that u just move your public folder content to root of your hosing and edit your index.php file and remove the **../** from the require __DIR__ path.